# Render the double value in the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I created a `JTable` with custom table model (MyTableModel.java) and I used some of `CellRenderer` class to view an effect of the cell. I have used `CustomTableCellRenderer` class to change the current cell as a green background. It's worked perfectly. At the same time, I have created a `RenderPrice` class to show the cell in decimal type, it takes the decimal value when I executed in first after if I edit the cell which is not updated and it will show the `$` sign as a prefix. I want to solve this. Please give some of solution as soon as possible. thanks

RenderPrice class code

```
class RenderPrice extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    Object result; 
    RenderPrice() { 
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);  
    }

    public void setValue(Object aValue) {
        result = aValue;
        if ((aValue != null) && (aValue instanceof Number)) {
            Number numberValue = (Number)aValue;
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            result = formatter.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
        } 
        super.setValue(result);
    }   
}
```

preceding code of my Tableclass (Accept.java)

```
gradeColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
gradeColumn.setCellRenderer(new RenderPrice());

gradeColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
gradeColumn.setCellEditor(new IntegerEditor(1,100));

gradeColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
gradeColumn.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

gradeColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
gradeColumn.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Comment: everything is in the majority/rest of your code, for better help sooner post an SSCCE or MCVE or MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JTable in JFrame with hardcoded value stored in local varibale for JTable/XxxTableModel

Comment: i cannot catch the point, please tell in detail

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** store any *state* in such a renderer. You are probably looking for something like this

```
class RenderPrice extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number))
        {
            Number numberValue = (Number)value;
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            String valueString = formatter.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
            setText(valueString);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: In response to the comments, and example

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class CurrencyCellEditorTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTable table = new JTable(
            new Object[][]{
                { 1.2, 3.4 },
                { 5.6, 7.8 }
            },
            new Object[] {
                "A", "B"
            });


        TableColumn column0 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column0.setCellEditor(new PriceEditor());
        column0.setCellRenderer(new PriceRenderer());

        TableColumn column1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        column1.setCellEditor(new PriceEditor());
        column1.setCellRenderer(new PriceRenderer());

        f.getContentPane().add(table);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class PriceRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    PriceRenderer()
    {
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object aValue)
    {
        Object result = aValue;
        if ((aValue != null) && (aValue instanceof Number))
        {
            Number numberValue = (Number) aValue;
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            result = formatter.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
        }
        super.setValue(result);
    }
}

class PriceEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    public PriceEditor()
    {
        super(createComponent());
        delegate = new EditorDelegate()
        {
            @Override
            public void setValue(Object value)
            {
                Number numberValue = 0.0;
                if (value != null && value instanceof Number)
                {
                    numberValue = (Number)value;
                }
                getFormattedTextField().setValue(numberValue);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getCellEditorValue()
            {
                try
                {
                    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                    String text = getFormattedTextField().getText();
                    Number number = numberFormat.parse(text);
                    return number;
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new Double(0.0);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static JTextField createComponent()
    {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(numberFormat);
        JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
        formattedTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        return formattedTextField;
    }

    private JFormattedTextField getFormattedTextField()
    {
        return (JFormattedTextField)getComponent();
    }

}
```

Comment: when first time of execution it will show in double form,but if i click on cell the $ sign hides and edited value is not changed as a double.can't i override setValue method here?

Comment: @user3391137 In this case, you'll also have to set the appropriate editor. See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=333472&seqNum=3 , for example

Comment: `You should not use (or override)` - sure you can. That method is used to set the value that should be rendered. It doesn't change the data in the model.

Comment: @camickr Well, *using* it may be OK, but overriding it (and storing the value that is passed in there for whatever reason) is at least dubious. Apart from not being the right approach here, one can hardly ever be sure whether someone calls "setValue" or "setText" - and if he calls the latter, then the overridden version of "setValue" will be bypassed...

Comment: The `setValue(...)` method is the method used set the text to be rendererd. This is in fact the approach used in the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). There is no need to override the getCellRendererComponent() method when you override the setValue() method.

Comment: @camickr OK, this might indeed be a simplification when one *only* wants to change the text (and not other renderer properties). I'll edit this a little...

Comment: @Marco13 well, i think so.How can i detect whether this setValue method is bypassed or not by another reasons?. Because the 1st time of execution ,it will render the correct form on cell.The problem arises when i edit on the cell.

Comment: @user3391137 As mentioned above: You'll also have to set an Editor. I added an EDIT with an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easy way to create your custom renderer. You just specify a specific Formatter.

In this case the class has a convenience method for currency formatting.

```
TableColumnModel m = table.getColumnModel();
m.getColumn(???).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());
```